# typescript complaining about valid javascript

Tags: typescript

This pretty much standard way of defining a javascript object (or namespace of functions) fails in typescript, saying that `publicFunction does not exist on type {}`. Is this by design?

```
var MyObject = function (){
  var that = {};

  var privateFunction = function () {};
  that.publicFunction = function () {};

  return that;
}();
```

PS: Found a "fix" to it by changing the first line to `var that = <any>{};` but I was wondering why is this necessary.

Comment: TypeScript has [internal and external modules](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript), you don't necessarily need to use this "standard way".

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of those but I already have tons of valid javascript in my existing project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript infers `that` to have type `{}`, an empty object. Probably it doesn't make much sense to have an object with any properties, though.

```
var that = {};
```

You've have worked around by assert it to have type `any`. Another way to do it is:

```
var that;
that = {};
```

This way TypeScript doesn't infer variable type.

To take profit of TS advantages, you're better at declaring all object members at once. If you can't, you could use an interface:

```
interface MyObjectInterface {
    publicFunction();
}

var MyObject = function (){
  var that = <MyObjectInterface>{};

  var privateFunction = function () {};
  that.publicFunction = function () {};

  return that;
}();
```

Answer (score 2):

Knowing nothing about typescript, I'm going to hazard a guess that, judging by its name, it is strictly-typed. This means you can't define properties on objects that weren't there when the object was created.

`<any>{}` overrides this restriction, giving you an object that you *can* define arbitrary properties on.

The "correct" way would probably be:

```
var that = {
    publicFunction: function () {}
};
```

Comment: Your guesses are all correct. One more thing to mention is that returning an `<any>{}` will make it impossible for the compiler to check further usages of that returned object...